# Conan CMake and Embarcadero integration

Tags: cmake, c++builder, conan

I am trying to make Conan with CMake run with Embarcadero Tokyo 10.2.3 compiler. I can do CMake with Embarcadero following it's tutorial. But issue seems to happen with Conan. So I do the `conan install`. Then I do `cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="bcc32c.exe" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="bcc32c.exe" -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=1 -G Ninja`. I get the error

> Incorrect 'Visual Studio'.  Toolset specifies compiler as 'MSVC' but CMake
>     detected 'Embarcadero'

The default conan profile shows `compiler=Visual Studio` which I believe is where the issue originates from. But dont know how to change it to Embarcadero (does not recognize) or if changing the default profile is the way to go. My CMakeLists.txt file looks like this (mostly default)

```
project(Timer)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()

add_executable(timer timer.cpp)
target_link_libraries(timer ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

The full cmake output is below:

```
-- The C compiler identification is Embarcadero 7.30.36015
-- The CXX compiler identification is Embarcadero 7.30.36015
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/Studio/19.0/bin/bcc32c.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/Studio/19.0/bin/bcc32c.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/Studio/19.0/bin/bcc32c.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/Studio/19.0/bin/bcc32c.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Current conanbuildinfo.cmake directory: C:/Mathew Joy/Source/mytimer/build
CMake Error at build/conanbuildinfo.cmake:579 (message):
  **Incorrect 'Visual Studio'.  Toolset specifies compiler as 'MSVC' but CMake
  detected 'Embarcadero'**
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  build/conanbuildinfo.cmake:237 (conan_check_compiler)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (conan_basic_setup)
```

Comment: I have posted an answer. For more interactive discussion about this topic, probably github issues or the CppLang slack conan channel would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to customize the default settings.yml file which can be found in `<userhome>/.conan/settings.yml`

This file has defined some of the most popular compilers, you might add something like:

```
compiler:
    sun-cc:
        ...
    gcc:
        version: ["4.1", "4.4", "4.5", "4.6", "4.7", "4.8", "4.9",

    Visual Studio:
        runtime: [MD, MT, MTd, MDd]
        version: ["8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "14", "15"]
        ...
    Embarcadero:
        version: ["V1", "V2"...]
```

This file can be shared and synchronized with the team and used in CI machines with the `conan config install` command.

Then you can add the values for convenience to your default profile, instead of the `Visual Studio` values.

It is likely that most of the logic that the built-in build helpers, like `CMake` are providing, would be limited for this compiler, as it doesn't recognize it. You can run your logic to call the build system directly if that is the case:

```
def build(self):
    self.run("cmake . -G ....")
    self.run("cmake --build . --config Release")
```

If you want to correctly build and create packages for different configurations, then you should parameterize the above using the settings and options, as necessary.

All of this assume that you will be creating and depending on your own packages, as the existing packages in the public conan-center repository will be for the popular compilers, so the binaries will be incompatible, and the recipes most likely won't implement building from sources with Embarcadero.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2019 C++ is much better than Embarcadero. I have used both Tokyo and the Rio version, and there is no comparison. In addition you can download the Managed C++, which is called C++ CLR (not CLI), which will allow you to integrate .NET forms/consoles with native C++ applications.

Visual Studio 2019 C++ works well when creating Xamarin IOS libraries, which can easily be integrated with C# for Xamarin Forms. Xamarin Forms works for both Android and IOS (Xamarin).

In July 2019, Embarcadero finally added 64 bit Mac OS operating system, and MAC has been 64 bit since 2008.

That should tell you something right there.